# glibc: custom handle for dymamic linker error

Tags: c, linux, glibc

In linux there is the following fatal error when the shared object library required for the binary can not be found:

`error while loading shared libraries: libabc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

This text is from glic library, file `elf/dl-error.c` function `_dl_signal_error`.

The question is how could I  (is it possible to) implement my own failure handler (in the binary file being started) to overcome issue with not found shared object. Sure, then I have to take a precautions not to call symbols from the missed library, but it is another question.

**upd:** This question is not about how to achieve the similar with dlopen (many people pointed to it). The question is rather about glibc/(load process) internals.

Comment: Load the names manually and error out on failure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) to open the shared libraries at runtime. the library is called `-ldl`

Comment: Thank you, you are right, but I've probably poorly formulated the question.